# ElasticSearch - Access array of date_range in painless script filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is there any way to access an array of date_range in a painless script filter?

My mapping for the "blocked_dates" field is as follows:

```
"blocked_dates": {
    "type": "date_range",
    "format": "strict_date"
},
```

Data looks like this:

```
"blocked_dates": [
    {
        "gte": "2019-07-12",
        "lte": "2019-07-14"
    },
    {
        "gte": "2019-07-16",
        "lte": "2019-07-18"
    }
],
```

I am using Amazon ElasticSearch v6.7 so I cannot use params._source in a script filter and if I try and access it via doc then I get an illegal_argument_exception.

```
"blocked_dates = doc['blocked_dates'].value; ",
"                    ^---- HERE"
```

> Fielddata is not supported on field [blocked_dates] of type [date_range]

I have a complex booking window requirement that checks if the chosen move-in and move-out date is within x days of another booking (blocked date) and this has to be done in a script.

I *could* do something hacky like store a copy of the array of date_range as a comma delimited (ie "2019-07-20,2019-09-12") string array. Then grab the string array from the painless script filter and parse the dates out of them.

But that is my last resort.

Comment: Why these type of questions does not answered by anyone. Facing the same issue and did not find a single answer on internet :(

Comment: Seems like not a lot of people use Painless scripting

Comment: @ArcadeRenegade Did you have any progress on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `params._source.blocked_dates.gte` (or `lte` depends on your needs), but keep in mind what it returned string, but not a date in your particular case.

In my case (float_range) solution was

```json
"script": {
  "lang": "painless",
  "source": "Float.parseFloat(params._source.price.gte)"
}
```

I think idea is pretty clear